# Google spreadsheet conditional formatting between two dates and another value

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to conditionally format each of the rooms so that they will be Red normally but green if the room will be available for a particular day.  The date of interest will be changed on the top left of the "Office Rooms" Tab. The values in the "Form Responses" Tab populate from a google form.

**Values to consider**:

1. Room numbers on the "Form Responses" Tab
2. Date range on the "Form Responses" tab
3. Date at the top of the "Office Rooms" Tab

I've tried IF statements and I know about using INDIRECT.  But I think this may just be too complicated for the normal "Conditional Formatting" route.  I may need to use Apps Script but I'm not too familiar with that yet.

I've posted a link to a copy of what I'm working on below.  Thank you in advance for any help you can throw my way!

**[Link to Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nVQGOeb9gL75bnQiDw1R6LCW3Pp4mwEIXwbk9xtwp_M/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with conditional formatting alone, using the following custom formula.

```
=isna(filter(indirect("'Form Responses'!B:D"), indirect("'Form Responses'!B:B") = B4, indirect("'Form Responses'!C:C") <= $C$2, indirect("'Form Responses'!D:D") >= $C$2))
```

As written, this can be applied to B4 and any range that has B4 as upper left corner. For other ranges, change B4 to its upper left corner.

Explanation: the `filter` command filters the indicated range according to criteria: B matches current cell, C and D are around the date stated in C2 of current sheet. If there is no match, then the result is #N/A and `isna` evaluates to True, triggering formatting (which would be red).

The formula would be a lot shorter if the data was on the same sheet. As is, one has to refer to `'Form Responses'!B:B` and such, which within a conditional formatting rule requires `indirect`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your formula worked like a charm.